# Как сделать проверку символов в файле на то чтобы это были цифры, а не буквы в c++?

Tags: c++, текст, char

Есть набор символов в текстовом файле. Как посимвольно проверить каждый на то, чтобы это была именно цифра, а не буква или какой-нибудь другой значок?

Comment: Посмотрите [`isdigit()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isdigit) - вы об этом?..

Answer (score 1):

для того, чтобы было побыстрее

1. считать весь файл в буфер (ну или кусками, если файл огромный)
2. сравнить, что символ в диапазоне от '0' до '9'
3. прервать выполнение программы, как только будет найдено несоответствие

Comment: По поводу 1 - файлы и так буферизованы, а с учетом вероятности того, что там будут только цифры - читать сразу все особого смысла нет.